# How to start laptop automatically when power restored

Tags: boot, laptop

I am configuring my laptop (Asus UX32A) without battery inside, to act as a 24/7 server. The AC power adapter will always be plugged in. I want the laptop to restart (automatically without having to press the power button) and boot when the power comes back on after a power outage.

Is this possible to configure? If yes, then how?
I have gone through the entire BIOS, but there are no such settings

Comment: Sounds like you may need to have an external backup power supply which can keep your ZEN logged on enough to save anything open in case the power goes out.

Comment: check if you can upgrade the bios ?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. It's not a problem for me if the laptop shuts down due to power failure. The thing that I want to solve, is that it should automatically reboot when the power comes back.

I have updated the bios with the BIOS update asus has available for the UX32A model.  The update added no additional configuration that I didn't already have.

Comment: Without a battery, a sudden power failure might leave the laptop in an unrecoverable state, unable to reboot without some help. Even a weak battery might be enough to allow smooth shutdown. That said, you might need a hardware hack, e.g. a trigger circuit to pulse the power switch when mains is up again; not all BIOS/UEFI have a power on auto setting. See https://www.technewsworld.com/story/86034.html

Comment: Thanks. I read through the article you sent, but I couldn't find any description of how to create some hardware adjustments to restart the laptop with. BIOS settings is dependant on a specific motherboard. So as I already miss BIOS configuration to restart the laptop when power is restored, it will probably be impossible to find an update that adds this, but I could be wrong..